# can't get localhost data from my phone (ionic)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm trying to make an ionic application so I try to connect it to localhost and get data (i use JSON-server "as a simple backend ")
and it is work on the pc I get data and I can modify it
but my application will use a native plugin so a have to test it from the phone but when I run it I can't get the data in the JSON-server the table of information is empty

I don't know what I have to do! please help

Comment: try using the IP address of your machine not localhost

Comment: how can I get the IP address I try ipconfig command and I get this :IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.158                                                              so the new http become :http://192.168.137.158:3000/jardTab is not working

Comment: with this new http i can't even get the data form the pc